# Showing random post from specific category on Wordpress

Tags: html, wordpress

I’m using the below code to show two images (which I've set up with Advanced Custom Fields) from a random post from in the category ‘homepage’ on each refresh. It doesn’t appear to be working however and when I google it there are so many different ways to do it! Does anybody know if mine looks correct? I’m concerned I might be missing a closing tag or something minor.

```
<div class="feature-container">

    <?php 
    $args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => 1, 
    'orderby' => 'rand', 
    'category_name' => 'homepage',
    );

    $loop = new WP_Query($args); 

    while ($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();

    if( have_rows('images') ):

        while ( have_rows("images") ) : 
            the_row();

            if ( get_sub_field( 'image' ) ): ?>

                <a href="<?php echo $link['url']; ?>" target="<?php echo $link['target']; ?>">
                    <div class="image feature-item">
                        <div class="overlay" style="background-color:<?php the_sub_field('hover_colour');?>">
                            <div class="caption pm-big">

                                <?php 

                                $link = get_sub_field('link');

                                if( $link ): ?>

                                    <?php echo $link['title']; ?>

                                <?php endif; ?>

                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <img src="<?php the_sub_field('image');?>" alt="" style="display: block;">
                    </div>
                </a>

        <?php else: ?>
            <!-- no images found -->
        <?php endif; 

            endwhile;

        else :

        // no images found

        endif;

    endwhile; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: You say that it is not working. Can you be more specific on how it is not working?

Comment: It's just showing the one post, here is the live version for reference… http://kateberry.wpengine.com/. There are two posts it could be cycling through.

Comment: Perhaps `posts_per_page` needs to be set to `2`?

Comment: So the issue is that you're always getting the same post, i.e. orderby rand isn't working? I'd suggest checking the SQL that the WP_Query is generating and test that removing the post limit in it does find both posts, and then make sure that the random order is working in SQL at least.

Comment: I tried 'posts_per_page' => 2 and that displayed both posts. So it seems that the 'orderby' => 'rand' isn't working. Apparently an "order" parameter needs to be present for "orderby" rand to work so I tried 'order' => 'ASC' (as suggested by somebody) and that hasn't worked either.

Comment: Okay so I've fixed it. Turns out it was a default setting in WP Engine that was blocking it. See post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35808245/wp-query-orderby-rand-not-working)